# Pass variable from parent directive to child-directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives that look like this:

```
<g-map centerlong="{{myLocation.long}}" centerlat="{{myLocation.lat}}" zoom="12" id="map" class="map">
    <g-marker poslong="{{myLocation.long}}" poslat="{{myLocation.lat}}" title="g-marker"></g-marker>
</g-map>
```

g-map creates a google map, and now I wish to apply g-marker to it.

Therefore g-marker needs access to the object created in g-map. How can I pass it

```
directive('gMap', function(googleMaps){
return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$on('location', function(){
                //här ska den recentreras
            })

        //create the map
        var center = googleMaps.makePosition(attrs.centerlat, attrs.centerlong)
        //update map on load
        var options = googleMaps.setMapOptions(center, attrs.zoom);
        scope.map = googleMaps.createMap(options, attrs.id) 
    }
    }]
};
}).
directive('gMarker', function(googleMaps, $timeout){
    return{
        //require: "^gMap",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
            var location = googleMaps.makePosition(attrs.poslat, attrs.poslong)
            $timeout(function(){
                                //this is where I want to access the scope.map variable
                googleMaps.addMarker(map, location,attrs.title)
            }, 0); 
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: It should have access, as you set `scope: true` instead of an isolated scope.

Comment: so what something like `console.log(scope.map)`` should work?

Comment: It should, go ahead and try it.

Comment: :) I tried it already, it's not part of the scope.

Comment: I am not sure you need to transclude in the parent directive. Can you try without ```transclude``` and ```template```?

Comment: The thing with google maps is that it wants a html-element to replace. If I don't use transclude, google maps replaces g-marker and it doesn't get rendered.

Comment: `googleMaps.addMarker(map` - shouldn't it be `scope.map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, googlempas replaces the html tag, so you use transclude, which makes the parent scope inaccessible to the child scope.

Here are some options:

The easiest solution is to make the parent scope non-isolate, so just remove `scope : true` in the parent directive, **and** set `scope.map` in the controller of the parent directive. This ensures that the property is immediately available in the child link function (no need for $timeout). however, if you are doing dom manipulation, you have to do it in the link function)

Or you could set up bi-directional data binding between parent and child directive: 
`scope : {map : '=map'}`

Or, if you prefer not to expose the whole map object to the child, you could expose a method of the parent scope that the child can call:

In gMap, create a controller:

```
controller : [function() {
 this.addMarker(location, title) 
}];
```

in gMarker, require the gMap:

```
require: "^gMap"
```

This injects the gMap controller into your link directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, gMapController){
  gMapController.addMarker(location, attrs,title)
}
```

I have made an example for each option in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1UyNVhFZl4HtFdqeYhie?p=preview

I'd prefer the third option, since it's not necessary that a child can access the whole map object.

Please note that it's possible that other factors can cause any of the options to fail. Please report back if it doesn't work.